# Reduce Loading time of Display:none Elements in Responsive Web Design

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have created a Responsive Design by using Display:none method for mobile. But when we use this method, the Element will Load and it causes high loading time. so is there any simple way to reduce loading time. I prefer some External JS Solving these issues.

Can anybody help me

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the load time is being increased by large images? One solution would be to use the Lazyload jQuery plugin which only loads images when they are within the viewport.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

I'm not sure if it will still load images that are not visible. However, you could instead use a class on elements which should not be visible, and then use this to position them outside of the viewport.

EDIT: Lazyload will skip hidden images by default. (See the bottom of the page linked above)

Comment: Unless you have a HUGE number of elements then you shouldn't notice any difference in load times... To the best of my knowledge there would be no way to remove these as javascript only interacts with the DOM not the actual html file.